# Javascript print is displaying hidden elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to built a billing system using php and javascript. For that I need to print some content in a new tab. I am using the following code for this purpose. Where the variable *divElements* contains the inner html of my table that needs to be print.

```
var print_body =
                  '<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"></link></head><body style="background:none"><table class="dop" id="table" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-style:solid">'+
                  divElements +'</table></body>';
                //Print  Page
                  newWin= window.open("");
                  newWin.document.write(print_body);
                  newWin.print();
```

using the class *dop* I am trying to hide the unwanted elements. In the print preview the the design displaying correctly but when taking printout, the hidden elements are printing in the paper.
I think the problem is print function is running before the style loads.
Please help me to solve the issue.

thanku

Comment: What does your css look like?  If you want to hide the table with class dop do you have `table.dop{display:none}` or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question, but you can load stylesheet(s) into your print view and perhaps set `display: none;` to elements.

Here is a function I use:

```
function print() {
    var popup = window.open('', 'print', 'height=600,width=700,scrollbars=yes');
    popup.document.write('<html><head><title>TITLE</title>');
    var printStylePath = '/Content/print.css';
    popup.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + printStylePath + '" type="text/css" />');
    popup.document.write('</head><body>');
    popup.document.write(printBody);
    popup.document.write('</body>');
    popup.document.write('</html>');
    popup.document.close();
    popup.focus();
    popup.print();
    popup.close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

Call document.close before print

```
var print_body = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"></link></head><body style="background:none"><table class="dop" id="table" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-style:solid">'+
                  divElements +'</table></body>';
                //Print  Page
                  newWin= window.open("");
                  newWin.document.write(print_body);
                  newwin.document.close();
                  newWin.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css use @media something like the following:

```
@media screen {
    p {
        font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media print {
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

So the element you want to hide or not displaying for printer define `@media print` for it.

For more resource about @media checkout [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)